# What's wrong with my JavaScript syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm writing a javascript slideshow, but Firebug is telling me there's an error in the syntax, or something, but I just can't see what's wrong!
Here's the code snippet:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var data = new Array();

var data[0] = new Array();
var data[0]['id'] = 'example';
var data[0]['height'] = 190;

</script>
```

Firebug says:

```
missing ; before statement  

var data[0] = new Array();
```

The problem? Well, I just don't understand where the problem is!
Could anyone explain the mistake to me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare an array index. Lose the `var` on all but the first line.

Comment: Right answer, and additionally you should not declare an array via `new Array();`, but via `[]`, because that is considered best practise. so the first line should say `var data = [];`

Comment: It also looks like he wants `{}` instead of `new Array` for the second line

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers! That fixed the problem. Also thank you for the 'best practice' tips!

Answer (score 0):

Keep only the first "var" statement, it will work like this:

```
var data = [];

data[0] = [];
data[0]['id'] = 'example';
data[0]['height'] = 190;
```

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/cmTBc/